# Email Service creating multiple Cases when sending to multiple aliases in a single email

Tags: apex, case, apex-email-service, email2case

Our org is currently using a custom Email Service to create cases and we have multiple Email Service aliases.

Currently, when a customer sends an email to multiple Email Service aliases, our service creates multiple cases in our org.

We would like to only create 1 case based on some stack ranking framework. Wondering if anyone has come across this and has any suggestions on how to create a single case in these scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

So, a solution to this might be of the following:

- Each inbound email service writes to a `Pending_Case__c` sobject the details needed to create a Case.
- A scheduled batch job runs every few minutes querying `Pending_Case__c` and de-dups (logic decides which email service address to use as the winner). A single Case is created; all component Pending_Case__c are either deleted or marked as "processed"

The query would need to look back at least a few minutes to make sure that any inbound email with multiple inbound email service to/cc: addresses have been processed by the inbound email handler so you don't hit any boundary conditions.